# Ignore regular HTML tags in regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex, vim

I need to find patterns in the text of an ugly HTML file. It's ugly because each character is wrapped in an absolutely-positioned `<span>`, and each `<span>` is on its own line, like this:

```
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:422px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">M</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:440px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">T</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:452px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">V</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:464px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:470px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">N</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:484px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">e</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:493px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">t</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:499px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">w</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:513px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">o</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:523px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">r</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:531px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">k</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:541px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">s</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:549px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">,</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:554px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:559px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">I</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:566px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">n</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:577px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">c</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:586px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">.</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:592px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">,</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:597px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:602px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:613px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">5</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:623px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:634px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:639px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">F</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:650px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">.</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:656px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">3</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:666px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">d</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:677px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:682px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:693px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:703px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">0</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:714px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:724px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:729px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">(</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:736px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:747px; top:3496px; font-size:13.6px;">t</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:751px; top:3496px; font-size:13.6px;">h</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:757px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:763px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">C</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:777px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">i</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:782px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">r</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:789px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">.</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:795px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:800px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:810px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:821px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:831px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">8</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:842px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">)</span>
```

This is the regex I would like to match (in Vim syntax): `[0-9]\+ F\.3d [0-9]\+`. So, in this example, I want to match `152 F.3d 1209`. I want to wrap that in an `<a>` to end up with this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:602px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:613px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">5</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:623px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:634px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:639px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">F</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:650px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">.</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:656px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">3</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:666px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">d</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:677px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:682px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:693px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:703px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">0</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:714px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
</a>
```

I could write a verbose regex to ignore every HTML tag, but that quickly becomes unworkable (for instance, it would be hard to match `[0-9]\+` if there is an HTML tag before and after each digit).

I could strip out the HTML using something like `%s/<.*>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/g`, but that doesn't work either, because I need to preserve the formatting.

I get that I [can't parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). But I don't need to parse arbitrary HTML; I just need to work around a known set of tags. Is there an elegant way to do this? Or should I abandon regexes and use something like an XPath parser?

I'm open to any language, but I'd prefer to work with Python, JavaScript, or Vim.

Comment: I can't see this "152 F.3d 1209" in the input. are you sure vim regex  [0-9]\+ F\.3d [0-9]\+ matches anything in the sample input? or I'm missing something.

Comment: @VinodSharma, scroll the input to the right, and then find "152 F.3d 1209" by reading the single-character values from top to bottom!  Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is missing a lot of error handling, and relies on a strict input format, but consider:

```
import re
import os

html = '''<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:422px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">M</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:440px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">T</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:452px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">V</span>
... (Lines omitted)
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:842px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">)</span>
'''

# This is sloppy, but if your input format remains the same should work...
chars = ''.join([line[line.find('>') + 1] for line in html.splitlines()])
# chars => "MTV Networks, Inc., 152 F.3d 1209 (9th Cir. 1998)"

# Use regex to search chars
mat = re.search(r'\d+ F\.3d \d+', chars)

# Extract lines from html based on the start and end positions of the regex match
block = html.splitlines()[mat.start():mat.end()]

# Wrap the lines with your anchor tag    
block = ['<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/>'] + block + ['</a>']

# Print the list
print os.linesep.join(block)
```

It first extracts the single characters inside the `<span>` tag and puts them in a string.  It then searches that string for your regex (modified for python's `re` module).

Since the position of the character in the `chars` string corresponds exactly to the line number of the corresponding line in `html`, we can use the start and end position of the match inside the `chars` string to select the lines of `html` we want to wrap.

We insert elements into the `block` list at the beginning and end, corresponding to your anchor tags, and print it.

As long as your input remains exactly as your specify, there's no need to invoke a DOM parser or anything very complex -- although it may turn out that something like that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would extract the text nodes to a simple string, match on it, then go back to the DOM tree to retrieve the initial HTML. Something like that:

```
import lxml.html, lxml.etree
import re

with open('foo.html') as f:
    source = lxml.html.parse(f)

letters = source.findall('//span')
string = ''.join(s.text for s in letters)

match = re.search(r'[0-9]+ F\.3d [0-9]+', string)
assert match is not None

start, end = match.span()
html = '\n'.join(lxml.etree.tostring(el).decode('utf8')
                 for el in letters[start:end])

print('<a href="foo">{}</a>'.format(html))
```

Please note that `tostring()` in a loop may not be the best as for performance. You should instead build the `a` element, append the letters in it and call `tostring()` on the `a` element once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using awk:

```
$ cat mornin.awk
NR == FNR {
    gsub("</?span[^<]*>","",$0)
    s = s $0
    next
}

FNR == 1 {
    i = match(s, "[0-9]+ F\.3d [0-9]+")
    len = RLENGTH
    print "<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com/\">"
}

FNR == i, FNR == (i + RLENGTH - 1)

END {
    print "</a>"
}
```

This solution requires two passes over the text, so you put the file twice on the command line:

```
$ awk -f mornin.awk mornin.txt mornin.txt
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:602px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:613px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">5</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:623px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:634px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:639px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">F</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:650px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">.</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:656px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">3</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:666px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">d</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:677px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;"> </span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:682px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">1</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:693px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:703px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">0</span>
<span style="position:absolute; color:black; left:714px; top:3497px; font-size:21.6px;">9</span>
</a>
```